# PHP MySQL Get material and quantity for an order form

Tags: php, checkbox

I need to create an order form that has a checkbox for each product in a table and have a quantity box next to each product.
I need to process the products that have been checked and update an orders table with the checked products and the quantity entered.

I don't know how to link the product checkbox to the quantity field.

```
$sql="select * from tproducts";

$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Product Names</th>";
echo "</tr>";
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
  echo "<form action=welcome1.php method=post>";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['intProductID'] . '" name="materialcode[]">' . $row['strProductName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>Enter Quantity </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='qty[]' value='qty' size=5></td>";  
    echo "</tr>";
  } 
} 
echo "</table>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />';
echo "</form>";
echo "</html>";

welcome1.php
<?php
echo "materialcode<br>";
print_r($_POST['materialcode']);
echo "<br>";
echo "qty<br>";
print_r($_POST['qty']);
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What do you mean by "link"?

Comment: I want to have a checkbox next to each product and a quantity field.  I then want to insert into my Orders table with the products and their corresponding quantities.  I don't know how to match up the materialcode[] array to the qty[] array.

Comment: Why not use a key in the array? What would happen if you try to submit the form (in the current state) and inspect the resulting values? Additionally, please add all such clarification to the question itself, not to the comment section

Comment: Nico Haase, I don't understand what you mean by "use a key in the array".

Comment: Here are the results in current state if I have three product checkboxes and I select the checkbox for the 2nd product and enter a qty of 3333. The issue is materialcode only has one array element but the qty array has three elements -materialcode Array ( [0] => 2 ) 
qty                 Array ( [0] => [1] => 33333 [2] => )

Comment: What do you mean by that? Which "results" are you talking about?

Comment: The results in welcome1.php. I added the code in welcome1.php above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will keep the key name you supply in the fields html.

```
  $productIndex = 0;   

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['intProductID'] . '" name="materialcode[$productIndex]">' . $row['strProductName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>Enter Quantity </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='qty[$productIndex]' value='qty' size=5></td>";  
    echo "</tr>";
    $productIndex++;
  }
```

This example uses numeric indexes but you could probably use `$row['intProductId']` as well.

In your php:

`$_POST['materialCode'][0]` will be the analog to `$_POST['qty'][0]` but only the checked checkboxes will be supplied.  You might end up with a `$_POST['materialCode']` array that has index 0, 5, and 7 if those were the only ones checked.

So use a foreach loop instead of a for loop.

```
foreach( $_POST['materialCode'] as $key => $value ){
    $productId = $value; 
    $quantity = $_POST['qty'][$key]; 
}
```